# I have given an assignment that includes a SQL query - I tried it but not given out appropriate result

Tags: sql

- `m-count` column includes bookid, totalwords, pages
- `m-books` column includes id, title, author, editor, isbn, year, url
- `m-wordscounts` includes bookid, wordid, count
- `m-words` includes id, word

How many unique words are there across all books unique means that word must appear once?

How many unique word are there per book? Design your query to display title alphabetically?

What are the top eight most frequently occurring word across all books?

What is the percentage of word count to total unique word per book?

Comment: *...i tried it...* Please show what you tried. Also read the online help here regarding how to properly use formatting in your question. It will help make your question easier to read.

Comment: Also these are too many questions for one post. SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: Please: only one question per question